# Replace Value with 225 if Result of Calculation is Less Than 225

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that takes the input of "a", runs a calculation and displays it in text field "c".

```
  $('input[name="c"]').val($('input[name="a"]').val().replace(/\,/g,'')*.03-5995);
```

If the result of the calculation is less than 225, I'd like it to just display 225 so that nothing below that figure is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the maximum function

```
$('input[name="c"]').val(Math.max(225, $('input[name="a"]').val().replace(/\,/g,'')*.03-5995));
```